# Как получить ссылку на изображение, зная ссылку на HTML страницу её содержащую?

Tags: html, python, парсер, распознавание

У меня есть массив ссылок на сайт, на котором сделан скриншот, такого типа: [image: http://prnt.sc/c0jkrl]

мне надо получить ссылку, которая у них в body хранится на само изображение http://image.prntscr.com/image/f81b70e684b64ddf8ef64e1e2334a5d6.png 
в целом, ссылку можно получить просто нажав "скопировать ссылку на изображение"
таких ссылок у меня 800 штук. Руками нераельно делать.

как мне программно лучше всего получить? 
Сайты никгода не парсил, но на уровне алгоритма все понятно.
Можете покидать референсы, что посмотреть лучше всего в моем случае.
Язык - пайтон

Comment: Это очень общий вопрос, потому что Вы не предоставили конкретики. Поэтому на него тоже можно ответить весьма общим образом: используйте регулярные выражения, готовые решения (как lxml) или разбирайте html руками.

Comment: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6774282#p6774282

Comment: Задача сводится к: 1. Загрузить HTML по заданной ссылке  2. Достать ссылку на картинку из HTML. Если у вас проблемы с последним, то приведите xpath, или css select выражение для ссылки (в браузере нажмите на что-нибудь вроде "inspect element"). Вот [пример кода, использующий xpath и регулярные выражения](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1734220/4279). Вот [пример кода, который показывает как достать информацию из HTML, используя произвольный критерий, с помощью `BeautifulSoup`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14338006/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'http://prnt.sc/c0jkrl'

r = requests.get(url)
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
img = html.xpath("//*[@name='twitter:image:src']/@content")[0]
```

Зависимости, lxml, requests

Недостаток, нет обработки ошибок, если нет изображения или файл не получен. Функции не делал, последние 3 строки оборачиваются в функцию и ими проходятся все ссылки.